# Github - revert to changes made online at github.com

Tags: git, github

I made some changes to my project using the web editor at github.com, and then accidentally ran a force push from my development server, which overwrote the changes I made online.

The GitHub.com commit history only shows the pushes I did from my server.
How can I roll back to the online changes I made?

Comment: Unless you pulled those commits locally at some point (in which case you could mess with the reflog), I think you're out of luck.

Comment: I found a tutorial about the very thing you asked https://medium.com/git-tips/githubs-reflog-a9ff21ff765f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found a tutorial about the very thing you asked medium.com/git-tips/githubs-reflog-a9ff21ff765f – evolutionxbox 1 hour ago

This fixed it for me. Thank you.

Github does log every change you make as a commit, but it's hard to find it via the Web UI. Using cURL works a treat.